# How do I call mongodb rest api through curl in php?

Tags: php, curl, mlab

Execuse me for my bad english.

I am new to mongolab.I want to know how to call mongolad rest api through curl in php.

I don't want to use mongodb driver.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (replace myApiKey with your api key form MongoLab):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases?apiKey=myAPIKey");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MongolabBot/1.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```